# Colorbox frame size calculated wrong (30px)

Tags: jquery, colorbox

as you can see here:
http://wakawaka.reh-kendermann.df-kunde.de/media/media
the colorbox content wrapper "cboxContent" height is 30 px too short.
We could say the content "cboxLoadedContent" / "cboxContent" is 30px too large.
In fact, when I correct the content 30px, the dsplay is right, but naturally the content has a specific height which is not changeable.

So: the whole calculation is wrong.
I am using Drupal 7.14 and
colorbox 7.x-1.3 ; A light-weight, customizable lightbox plugin for jQuery 1.4.3+. and 
jQuery Update 7.x-2.2 ; Updates jQuery to jQuery 1.5.2 and jQuery UI 1.8.11.

Thanx for help

Lars

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I believe this is due to the box-sizing method you are using.  The colorbox.css file being used here is a bit out of date.  Try adding the following line and see if it fixes your issue:

```
#colorbox, #cboxContent, #cboxLoadedContent{box-sizing:content-box;}
```

Comment: i don´t think, it´s a css problem. You can see on other colorbox sites, that the inline-styles has a difference of 28/30px and the colorbox css should fit the module version i used.
Anyway thx for help.
Or does the javascript calculate the inline styles as a process.. meaning when i alter the css of the content box, the Javascript sets the width and height after the formating of the box?
BTW: i tried your css and it didn´t work.

Comment: it does :-)
 #cboxContent, #cboxLoadedContent {padding-bottom:15px;} did it.

Answer (score 0):

Colorbox really calculates dimensions after css is applied.
`#cboxContent, #cboxLoadedContent {padding-bottom:15px;}` 
did it. 
Greetings Lars